# Dictionary returned empty when called from other function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to access a dictionary from other function (both the functions are in same class). But this is returning me empty dictionary.

```
class c1():
  def __init__(self):
       self.test = {}

  def func1(self,**dict1):
      pprint(dict1)       ## dict1 to this functions is passed from other python file and I am able to print this dict1 within in this function without any problem ##
      return dict1
  def func2(self):
     self.test = self.func1() # After adding changes suggested still returning empty dict
```

Comment: Well, you should have a `return` statement

Comment: Moses, thanks for quick suggestion. After adding your and Pablo's changes still see to doesnt work. Below are the included changes

Comment: class c1(): def __init__(self): self.test = {} def func1(self,**dict1): pprint(dict1) ## dict1 to this functions is passed from other python file and I am able to print this dict1 within in this function without any problem ## return dict1 def func2(self): self.test = self.func1() # STILL EMPTY DICT HERE

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return statement in `func1()`.

Also, you are calling func1() with no arguments, even though it expects an unpacked dictionary.

You can try the following:

```
def func2(self):
  self.test = self.func1(name='Pablo')
```

Also I believe that in your `__init__()`, `test` should be `self.test`

Comment: Right, I tried as per your and Moses sugestions. But still seem not to work.

Comment: class c1():
  def __init__(self):
       self.test = {}

  def func1(self,**dict1):
      pprint(dict1)       ## dict1 to this functions is passed from other python file and I am able to print this dict1 within in this function without any problem ##
      return dict1
  def func2(self):
     self.test = self.func1() # STILL EMPTY DICT HERE

Comment: @krishna please don't post code in the comments. It's completely unreadable. Edit your post above instead.

Comment: made changes. Please help ASAP

Comment: @krishna I updated my response. You are caling func1() with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks very much. But  in this 'self.func1(name='Pablo')' does 'name' mean the dict i should refer to? like self.func1(name='dict1')? If it so..it is printing something like this {'name': 'dict1'}. But I am expecting the entire and exact dictionary to be printed in func2. sorry for being dumb.